# Clang won't see headers

Tags: c++, makefile, clang

I update clang and apparently it forgets where to find the standard library ie

```
reactions/baseReaction.cc:11:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
```

I install libc++ with

```
 sudo apt-get install libc++-dev
```

but when I try

```
ln -s /usr/bin/c++ /usr/bin/clang++-libc++
```

it gives

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/clang++-libc++’: File exists
```

and I still cannot use make

EDIT: tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --config c++
```

and

```
CXX=clang++-libc++ make
```

no joy so far

EDIT2: modifying the makefile with CXX=clang++-libc++ seems to have worked.

Comment: `ln -s /usr/bin/c++ /usr/bin/clang++-libc++` looks like a very bad idea. Try `CXX=clang++-libc++ make` instead (but there are probably other problems too).

Comment: Okay I stupidly did this through the cmdline rather than the makefile, it seems to have worked

Answer (score 2):

More advisably than manually creating the symlink, since you seem to be on a Debian-based system, you could try `sudo update-alternatives --config c++` to have the OS create that symbolic link for you. It should bring up a selection of all the C++ compilers you have installed on your systems. (See also the manpage for `update-alternatives` for future reference, either locally or [online here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).)

---

Note that if you meant for the file `/usr/bin/c++` to be a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/clang++-libc++`, your argument order is wrong. A good rule of thumb is that you use the same argument order for `ln` as you would use for `cp` or `mv`.

Comment: another good idea is to use the -i flag on ln so it asks you before overwriting something that exists.  that way if the order is backwards, it asks you if you want to overwrite the thing you're trying to duplicate and that's obviously wrong.

Comment: I tried sudo update-alternatives --config c++ and while it will allow me to select different compiler frontends it still won't work. I also tried the solution in the first comment but it still cannot find the vector header.

Comment: To check, do you actually have the files on your system? Does `find /usr/include/c++ | grep vector` produce actual header files?

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.8/debug/vector
/usr/include/c++/4.8/vector
et al